# SearchView and ABS

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

Previously I had an `EditText` with a `onTextChangedListener` to handle the users search queries. This was done this way:

ed.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

```
            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {

                textLength = ed.getText().length();
                list.clear();
                isPresent = initIsPresentArray();

                for (int i = 0; i < tempList.length; i++) {
                    for (int j = 0; j < (tempList[i].length() - (textLength - 1)); j++) {
                        if (textLength <= tempList[i].length()) {
                            if (isPresent[i] == false) {
                                if (ed.getText()
                                        .toString()
                                        .equalsIgnoreCase(
                                                (String) tempList[i]
                                                        .subSequence(
                                                                j,
                                                                (j + textLength)))) {
                                    list.add(tempCaseList.get(i));
                                    isPresent[i] = true;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if (list.size() == 0) {
                        error.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.notFound));
                        v.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    } else {
                        error.setText("");
                        v.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    }

                    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(History.this, list));
                }
            }
        });
```

This nasty piece of code updates a ListView  on the fly, while the user types in what to search for. It works quite nice with an `EditText`. Now, I'm implementing ActionBarSherlock to my project, and want to use the SearchWidget:

[image]

I have inflated my menu:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.actionbarmenu, menu);
        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView)menu.findItem(R.id.searchCases).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
        return true;
    }
```

How can apply the same behaviour as the `OnTextChangedListener` to this `SearchView`? Is it possible?

Comment: Did you looked at the `OnQueryTextListener`(link available: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SearchView.OnQueryTextListener.html )?

Comment: Also, you should really use the `Filter` to actually filter an adapter instead of that pseudo filtering in the `TextWatcher` that I keep seeing around here.

Comment: Good point, thanks for the heads up!